# List specific info from multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, select

I have three tables: computer, pc, and employee. I am trying to find the name of the computer model used by employees with the name Tracy. I'll put in examples of each table. A line that would be involved, and a line that isn't involved.

The computer table

```
 comp |   MFR   |  PROCT
+-----+---------+-------+
|C101 | COMPAQ  | 486DX |
+-----+---------+-------+
|D111 |  Dell   |  simm |
+-----+---------+-------+
```

The pc table

```
 tagnum | comp | local | empnum
+-------+------+--------+-------+
|77740  | C101 | Acct   |  625  |
+-------+------+--------+-------+
|37692  | H125 |  Home  |  456  |
+-------+------+--------+-------+
```

The employee table

```
 empnum  |   empname   |  empphone |
+--------+-------------+-----------+
| 625    | Tracy S     |   1311    |
+--------+-------------+-----------+
| 119    |  Robert O   |   1312    |
+--------+-------------+-----------+
```

My reasoning is that it should be this:

```
select * 
from computer 
INNER JOIN pc ON computer.COMP=pc.comp 
INNER JOIN employee ON pc.empnum=employee.empnum
where employee.empname='Tracy%'`
```

But it's not working and I can't figure out what I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: It should be `LIKE 'Tracy%`' instead of `='Tracy%'`.

Comment: OH my gosh I can't believe I was missing something like that. I even had a n answer two questions earlier where I needed to use `LIKE`. Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Comment: Also, when you are troubleshooting, eliminate the where and see if that part works. A general "it's not working" should be embarrassing if you are a pro. does the first join work? Does the second? Does the where clause work. If you know where it breaks down, then you can figure it out for yourself.

Comment: Well I'm not a pro in this language by any stretch. I'm currently a college student. I'm never sure if I should be posting here or in the DBA site instead. That is how I have been getting through my other issues, but this was something I was just completely overlooking because I'm not familiar with the baseline syntax logic yet.

Comment: @bonzo, Instead of adding `[solved]` in the title, accept one of the answers.

Comment: I do not know how to accept a comment to the OP, only vote a comment useful. Or I could accept another answer.

Comment: Alright. I just wanted to make sure, seeing as it was your answer that really got me. I'm glad I could effectively demonstrate how new I am tonight. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * 
from computer 
INNER JOIN pc ON computer.COMP=pc.comp 
INNER JOIN employee ON pc.empnum=employee.empnum
where employee.empname like 'Tracy%'`
```

% operator should using like instead of = operator.